# How to distinguish between video call log and voice call log white writing in call logs manually

Tags: android, calllog

I have written code to  write in call logs. What field I should to write or distinguish between voica call and video call.

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, i+200);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, time);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
                    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION,0);


                    getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

What field should I use to distuingish between a voice call and video call.
By default it is voice call.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html - maybe it's not possible

Comment: I'm interested in this too. While reading the call Log is possible to check if it was voice or video call? Thanks